# How do I return a constrained integer from a number in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, orm, dapper

In Oracle-speak, this would be a `NUMBER(9, 0)` or anything that maps to a 32-bit (or even a 16- or 64-bit) integer.

```
CREATE TABLE T(C1 NUMBER, C2 NUMBER(9, 0) ); -- Unconstrained and constrained number
INSERT INTO T(C1, C2) VALUES (10, 10);

SELECT C1, C2 FROM T; -- C1 is NUMBER, C2 is NUMBER(9,0)
```

Oracle assumes a precision and scale, then appears to have no means to set them short of modifying the table structure itself:

```
SELECT
    CAST(C1 AS INTEGER) FAILURE1, -- Unconstrained number
    TRUNC(C1)           FAILURE2, -- Unconstrained number
    ROUND(C1, 0)        FAILURE3, -- Unconstrained number
    CAST(ROUND(C1, 0) AS NUMBER(9, 0)) FAILURE4, -- Unconstrained number
    TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(PERCENT_DONE, '99') FAILURE5, -- ~Overcomplicated and still fails
FROM T
```

This makes the authoring of applications which work with Oracle more difficult, and also makes them slower and less memory efficient. ORMs like Stack Overflow's own [Dapper](https://github.com/DapperLib/Dapper) and their underlying drivers have no idea what the unconstrained number might contain, so they map these columns to types, like [`System.Decimal`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.decimal), rather than just a simple integral type.

Oracle does have `TO_BINARY_FLOAT()` and `TO_BINARY_DOUBLE()` which maps to float and double respectively, but how can this be done with an integer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I put together a minimal example to show the problem.

In Oracle: `CREATE TABLE my_schema.T(c1 NUMBER(9,0) NOT NULL, c2 NUMBER NOT NULL)`

The following complete C# console app can be pasted over a new project's Program.cs to demonstrate:

```
using System.Data;
using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client;
 
// Normally you want to use Dapper or EF and not the raw driver calls.
// The presence of the SQL and cstr in this file are for demonstration purposes only.
var connection = new OracleConnection();
connection.ConnectionString = "SOME CONNECTION STRING";
using var cmd = new OracleCommand();
cmd.CommandText = """
    SELECT
        c1,
        c2,
        CAST(C1 AS INTEGER) i1,
        CAST(C2 AS INTEGER) i2,
        TRUNC(C1)           t1,
        TRUNC(C2)           t2,
        ROUND(C1, 0)        r1,
        ROUND(C2, 0)        r2,
        CAST(ROUND(C1, 0) AS NUMBER(9, 0)) rc1,
        CAST(ROUND(C2, 0) AS NUMBER(9, 0)) rc2,
        CAST(C1 AS NUMBER(18, 0)) rc1,
        CAST(C2 AS NUMBER(18, 0)) rc2
    FROM my_schema.T
    """;

cmd.Connection = connection;
connection.Open();
using IDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
while(reader.Read()) {
    for(var columnCount = 0; columnCount < reader.FieldCount; columnCount++) {
        Type type = reader.GetFieldType(columnCount);
        var val = reader.GetValue(columnCount);
        var fieldName = reader.GetName(columnCount);
        Console.WriteLine($"{fieldName}:{val}:{type}");
    }
}
```

This yields:

```
C1:100:System.Int32
C2:100:System.Decimal <-- Want C2 as a NUMBER(9,0) or similar
I1:100:System.Decimal
I2:100:System.Decimal
T1:100:System.Decimal
T2:100:System.Decimal
R1:100:System.Decimal
R2:100:System.Decimal
RC1:100:System.Int32 <-- ✅
RC2:100:System.Int32 <-- ✅
RC1:100:System.Int64 <-- ✅
RC2:100:System.Int64 <-- ✅
```

Those last four rows with Int32 and Int64, are what I need.
Decimal = bad, unless we really do need a 128-bit struct type to store the value.

**`CAST()` changes the outgoing data type**.
My original post showed this returning an unconstrained number, but apparently, I was mistaken. My original test had a ROUND wrapping the CAST, which I did not expect to drop all information about precision and scale.

Comment: As noted in my answer, the Oracle `INTEGER` data-type is an alias for `NUMBER(38)` so using `CAST(column_name AS INTEGER)` you are telling Oracle to change to using a data type that is too big to fit in a 64-bit number. [`ROUND(n,0)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/ROUND-number.html#GUID-849F6C45-0D72-4464-9C0F-8B6822BA85E1) and [`TRUNC(n)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/TRUNC-number.html#GUID-911AE7FE-E04A-471D-8B0E-9C50EBEFE07D) should both return the same data type as `n`.

Comment: `NUMBER(38,0)` is indeed an integer in terms of mathematics, so that does make sense. You have made a good case that my expectation that `ROUND` returns a smaller value is not a reasonable one, or at least that it is based on a register-centric expectation that should not affect Oracle's platform-agnostic data type. Thank you for taking the time to correct my error, as it will help with my mental model of Oracle type handling in general, not just in this specific case.

Answer (score 2):

#### Storage of Oracle's `NUMBER` Data Type

In Oracle, a `NUMBER` is an exact numeric data-type that is represented as 1 byte for the exponent and 1 byte for every two digits of the number.

If, for your sample data, you use:

```sql
SELECT DUMP(C1), DUMP(CAST(C1 AS NUMBER(9,0))), DUMP(C2) FROM T;
```

Then you will see the binary values that are returned by the query:

| DUMP(C1) | DUMP(CAST(C1ASNUMBER(9,0))) | DUMP(C2) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Typ=2 Len=2: 193,11 | Typ=2 Len=2: 193,11 | Typ=2 Len=2: 193,11 |

As you can see, the database does not pass data about the underlying column data type with the value, it only passes the value (and using `CAST` does not change the value).

Even though the underlying column is a `NUMBER` or `NUMBER(9,0)`, the database is only passing 2-bytes of information which, in this case, is more efficient than using a 32-bit (4-byte) or 64-bit (8-byte) integer.

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Ctpz9LpR)

---

#### Oracle's Numeric Data Types

Oracle has the [data types](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlqr/Data-Types.html#GUID-7FDD9381-7E1F-45FC-97FA-4CAFE1705350):

- `NUMBER(p, s)` - which stores exact values with a scale from -84 to +127 and precision of 1 to 38 decimal digits.

  - `NUMERIC` and `DECIMAL` - which are aliases for `NUMBER`
  - `FLOAT(p)` - a sub-type of `NUMBER` with a precision of 1 to 126 binary digits (i.e. `NUMBER(1)` to `NUMBER(38)`). `FLOAT` and `DOUBLE PRECISION` are aliases for `FLOAT(126)` and `REAL` is an alias for `FLOAT(63)`.
  - `INTEGER`, `INT` and `SMALLINT` - are aliases for `NUMBER(38)`
- `BINARY_DOUBLE` - 64-bit floating point number.
- `BINARY_FLOAT` - 32-bit floating point number.

> Oracle does have TO_BINARY_FLOAT() and TO_BINARY_DOUBLE() which maps to float and double respectively, but how can this be done with an integer?

There is no `BINARY_INTEGER` data type in Oracle SQL (it does exist in PL/SQL). What you are asking for does not exist in Oracle; there is only `NUMBER`, `BINARY_FLOAT` or `BINARY_DOUBLE`.

---

#### Database Drivers

However, what you are asking for is nothing to do with the internals of the Oracle database; instead, it relates to how the database driver that talks to the database returns the value to the third-party programming language.

For example, the Data Provider for .NET Developer Guide documentation has a section on [Mapping Oracle Data Types to EDM Types](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/23/odpnt/entityEDMmapping.html#GUID-47AB0154-D89E-4CA0-AB6C-F5BF3D57CE5F):

> Table 4-1 Mapping of Oracle Data Types and EDM Types
>
> | Oracle Data Types | EDM Types(Primitive-TypeKind) |
> | --- | --- |
> | Binary_Double | Double |
> | Binary_Float | Single |
> | Binary_Integer | Int32 |
> | Float | Decimal |
> | Int | Int32 |
> | Number(1,0) Number(2,0) Number(3,0) Number(4,0) Number(5,0) | Int16 |
> | Number(6,0) Number(7,0) Number(8,0) Number(9,0) Number(10,0) | Int32 |
> | Number(11,0) Number(12,0) Number(13,0) Number(14,0) Number(15,0) Number(16,0) Number(17,0) Number(18,0) Number(19,0) | Int64 |
> | Number (all other cases) | Decimal |
> | Smallint | Int16 |

Which suggests that, for that driver, what you want is already done.

Comment: `DUMP()` may not include the detailed type, but I am not using DUMP(). It also doesn't include nullability.
Oracle must pass the type information to the driver in some way or the client would be unable to distinguish, say, `NUMBER(11,0)` from `NUMBER(10,0)`, though perhaps not as part of the `SELECT`.
These can still be found with `DESC T` which returns, for example `C1 NOT NULL NUMBER(9)` or `C2 NOT NULL NUMBER` (for unconstrained number C2)
That said, the table that you found (I failed to find such a table) and thoughtful answer were helpful, so add another + to your impressive 150K.

Answer (score 0):

You can use constraints on your columns to ensure that values fit into the 32-bit signed limits:

```
CREATE TABLE T
 (C1 NUMBER,
  C2 NUMBER(10, 0)
    CONSTRAINT T_C2_VALUE_CHECK
      CHECK(C2 BETWEEN -2147483648 AND 2147483647))
```

No idea if an/your ORM can make use of this information.

[db-fiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/MH3oO_0r)

Comment: Thank you for the answer, and I do like constraints. Unfortunately, the ORM would need to actively interpret constraints in order to use this to determine the type.